# Get Timestamp in ML.NET Anomaly detection

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net, anomaly-detection

Im following this tutorial: [anomaly-detection with ML.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sales-anomaly-detection) where the results looks like this:

```
Alert   Score   P-Value 
0       271.00  0.50    
0       124.30  0.13    
1       341.50  0.00 <-- Spike detected
0       197.80  0.48    
0       127.90  0.13
```

but in my data i also have a timestamp. Is it possible to see the timestamp in the results?

```
Alert   Score   P-Value Timestamp
0       271.00  0.50    2022-06-01: 22:30:15
0       124.30  0.13    2022-06-01: 22:30:20
1       341.50  0.00    2022-06-01: 22:30:25 <-- Spike detected
0       197.80  0.48    2022-06-01: 22:30:30
0       127.90  0.13    2022-06-01: 22:30:35
```

If it is not possible, how do i use the results?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a column in your dataset, you can define it in your Input / Output classes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sales-anomaly-detection#create-classes-and-define-paths

Add a property to the classes for your TimeStamp column. i.e.

```cs
public class ProductSalesData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string Month;

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public float numSales;

    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public string TimeStamp;
}

public class ProductSalesPrediction
{
    public string TimeStamp;

    //vector to hold alert,score,p-value values
    [VectorType(3)]
    public double[] Prediction { get; set; }
}
```